# Breaking the loop after string check in python

Tags: python, iteration

I have the following list:

```
str_list = [1,3,"foo bar",10]
```

What I want to do is to simply iterate through it
print the results. Stop if the iteration meets "foo bar".

I tried the following code:

```
In [6]: for x in str_list:
   ...:     print x
   ...:     if x is "foo bar":
   ...:         break
   ...:
```

It continues to print string with and after "foo bar".
It didn't to to what I expect it to do, i.e. simply printing this:

```
1
3
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[itertools.takewhile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) was written specifically for this purpose, though I am not a particular fan as it add an unnecessary function call through lambda and often its difficult to debug

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> for elem in takewhile(lambda e: e != "foo bar", str_list):
    print elem


1
3
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to print after checking. And if it is the string you are looking for in the check, just break. Like this:

```
>>> str_list = [1,3,"foo bar",10]
>>> for item in str_list:
...     if item == 'foo bar':
...         break
...     print item
...
1
3
```

Also, it is important to note the difference between using `is` and using `==`. As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python), `is` checks if both the variables point to the same object. `==` checks if objects referred to by the variables are equal. So you should be using `==` here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to print the items of the list after you check for the desired string.

```
for x in str_list:
    if x == "foo bar":
        break
    print(x)
```

However there are more pythonic ways of doing this:

```
 try:
     foo_idx = str_list.index('foo bar')
 except ValueError:
     print(str_list)
 else:
     print(str_list[:foo_idx])
```

And if you wanted this to return something formated like you were showing in your questions:

```
 try:
     foo_idx = str_list.index('foo bar')
 except ValueError:
     print('\n'.join(map(str, str_list)))
 else:
     print('\n'.join(map(str, str_list[:foo_idx])))
```

Comment: I would enjoy the feedback from all the down voters.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but your second implementation is overtly complex. Remember `Simple is better than complex`

Comment: @Abhijit Thanks for the feedback.  I tried to highlight python's duck typing and return a string like the one in the question.

Comment: Yes, but this was probably not a very good example to show duck typing. In fact, I do not see any merits out here to do so. Remember "If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it probably is a duck" , but how can you apply the duck test here?

Comment: @Abhijit, good point, I miss typed! What I was trying to showcase was the "it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" mentality that, for the most part, is encouraged over the "look before you leap" style.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this is by splitting using your desired value ...

Let us say that you have the list

```
s = [1,3,"foo bar",10]
```

Then,

```
s[:s.index('foo bar')]
```

is a list till the location of `'foo bar'`. Of course, if 'foo bar' isn't in the list, then it will throw an error. Then you can change the above line to

```
s[:s.index('foo bar')] if 'foo bar' in s else s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str_list = [1,3,"foo bar",10]

for x in str_list:
     if x is "foo bar":
         break
     print x
```